# Weinre not finding a target device - Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, weinre

I am trying to debug my hybrid cordova app using weinre (following this [guide](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/))

**192.168.1.202** is the IP of my pc.

I have run my weinre server using this

```
weinre --boundHost 192.168.1.202
```

then displayed my client interface using this

http://192.168.1.202:8080/client/#anonymous

added the folling line to my html page

```
 <script src="http://192.168.1.202:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

and run my app.

My device (wp8.1) is on the same network as my pc. My firewall has been turned off on private network.

Why my target device is not identified (as displayed below)?

PS: I have an express version of Visual Studio so I dont have any another way to debug my hybrid app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My firewall must be disabled on public network as well. This answers my post and makes it work.